# Database structure, user, category, answer, interval

Tags: sql, database, structure

I am designing a database that has many users. Each user is tied to many questions. Each question has one answer. Each question is tied to one category. There is also an interval table that I track the next time a user is due to be asked a particular question along with the interval that question is asked.

**user table**
- userid
- username
- password
-email
-created
-lastlogon

**question table**
- questionid
- question
- answer

**category table**
- categoryid
- category
- questionid

**interval table**
- userid
- questionid
- interval
- nextdate

Is this the correct approach/design for this data?

I was debating about combining the category and question table, would that be a good idea? Or I was thinking of making a linking table to store just the categoryid's and questionid's, but I am not so sure about that design. If I am not clear enough on, please just ask I will attempt to clarify.

Comment: You should have the category id in the question table, not the other way around like you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would probably do it:

```
CREATE TABLE [Users] (UserID, Username, Password, Email, Created, LastLogon)

CREATE TABLE [Questions] (QuestionID, Question, Answer, Interval, CategoryID)

CREATE TABLE [Categories] (CategoryID, Category)

CREATE TABLE [User_Intervals] (UserID, QuestionID, NextDate)
```